# how do I get python to run a exe and reference a file

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

Quick note: This is on a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) environment.

I am working on a script to run femzip on all files and folders in a shared drive. I have a batch file that does something similar. Issue is, it is depended on a `run1` folder. Anyway, I was wondering how do I get Python to to run the exe and reference the `pfile`?

I will post the batch script and what I have so far. What I have so far should check all files and folders. The file I want to zip, its not complete, but its part of the whole thing. The purpose is to check for the file if it`s there, zip it using femzip (*have to use femzip the gzip Python module is not going to work*) and if its not, then ignore and move to the next folder.

Translating from batch file:

```
set back=%cd%
set FEMZIPEXE=C:\FEMZIP\FEMZIP_8.68_dyna_NO_OMP_Windows_VS2008_MT_x64\femzip_dyna.exe
set FEMZIPPROFILE=C:\FEMZIP\FEMZIP_8.68_dyna_NO_OMP_Windows_VS2008_MT_x64\EVZ_lsdyna_femzip_181115.pfile

for /d %%i in (D:\RESCALE_RESULTS\*) do (cd "%%i\run1" & call %FEMZIPEXE% -Id3plot -OZd3plot -L4 -C%FEMZIPPROFILE% )
cd %back%
pause
```

Python code that I have so far:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

#going to use the os module to check file and folders in windows

count = 0
for (dirname, dir, files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.startswith('d3plot'):
            count = count + 1
        if filename.startswith('d3plot'):
            subprocess.Popen([r"C:\FEMZIP\FEMZIP_8.68_dyna_NO_OMP_Windows_VS2008_MT_x64\femzip_dyna.exe"])
            subprocess.Popen([r"C:\FEMZIP\FEMZIP_8.68_dyna_NO_OMP_Windows_VS2008_MT_x64\EVZ_lsdyna_femzip_181115.pfile"])
        else:
            break
```

Comment: `"\f"` is a form feed character. You need to escape it: `"\\f"`.

Comment: Why are you using `Call`? I'd suggest that you remove it. You should also be using `CD /D "%%i\run1"` not `cd "%%i\run1"` and `CD /D "%back%"` not `cd %back%`. I'd also recommend this `Set` syntax, `Set "back=%cd%"`.

Comment: my role in this is more on the python side, the batch script was more of a quick and dirty fix by a co-worker doing googling he gave me the batch script and I decided to use python since the endgame of this will be it will run on a qnap and auto zip the drive with all these files

Comment: If you didn't want batch file help, you shouldn't have posted a batch file and used the [tag:batch-file] tag!

Comment: its not that I dont want batch file help, it is that is not priority, the reason I posted the batch file and used the batch file tag was to show  the resource I am using

Comment: If you want to translate the `call` line to `subprocess`, then you may only need 1 instance of `subprocess`, and add the arguments to the command List. i.e. without paths only to reduce display: `["femzip_dyna.exe", "-Id3plot", "-OZd3plot", "-C" + FEMZIPPROFILE]`.

Comment: thank you for the assistance I will give it a try,
something like this
`code
if filename.startswith('d3plot'):
   subprocess.Popen([["femzip_dyna.exe", "-Id3plot", "-OZd3plot", "-C" + FEMZIPPROFILE])
  else:
   break 
`

Comment: this may be a dumb question and I apologize if it is one but can I use this
`code
import os
os.startfile("C:\FEMZIP\FEMZIP_8.68_dyna_NO_OMP_Windows_VS2008_MT_x64\femzip_dyna.exe")
os.startfile("C:\FEMZIP\FEMZIP_8.68_dyna_NO_OMP_Windows_VS2008_MT_x64\EVZ_lsdyna_femzip_181115.pfile")
`

Comment: @user11536476 Create a test environment and test it. I cannot find required details about Femzip online without requesting an evalutation license to access. All I know is that how you are running Femzip in the batch-file code is different in the Python code. Changing `subprocess.Popen` to `os.startfile` may achieve different behavior though the arguments are still different to the batch-file. Sorry if I cannot be of more help. Note: Ensure backslashes are escaped ``\\`` or use **r**aw strings `r""`.

Comment: @michael_heath thanks for all the help was that was given, the test environment will be created most likely next week, I volunteered for this so I could get better at learning python, my main question I suppose was that I need to open the femzip.exe and have it look at the pfile and was hoping that I am doing it the right way using subprocesses then I found os,startfile so i was confused which one to use I will see how the test environment reacts :)